# Who was Beni calling a "bastard" in The Mummy?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mummy

Who was the Mummy's morally destitute henchman (formerly Rick O'Connell's sidekick) Beni calling a bastard when Imhotep caused Winston's plane to crash? I just watched the film again, and I can never tell if the slur is directed at the creature, or at Rick.

Comment: My take was that he was complimenting Imhotep ("*Well done, Boss*") as he walked past, then as it became clear that he'd moved out of earshot, he called him a bastard for having killed O'Connell.

Answer (score 3):

**The slur is directed toward Rick O'Connell.**  The scene in the desert involving Imhotep, Beni and Evelyn watching Rick, Jonathan and Winston's plane go down:

(Imhotep creates the sandstorm to attempt to crash the plane)

Evelyn:

> Stop it, you'll kill them.

Beni:

> That's the idea.

When Beni says this, he is speaking very casually as if it does not bother him in the least that Rick is in danger.

(Plane crashes in the sand)

Beni to Imhotep:

> I love the whole sand wall trick.  It was beautiful.

Beni is praising Imhotep by saying this.

Beni:

> **Bastard.**

**Beni definitely says this implying that Rick is the "Bastard"**.  Beni is looking in the direction of the plane crash with a satisfied look and says "Bastard" in a gratified tone implying that Rick deserved the fate of having his plane crash.